# What does the ++counter mean?

Tags: java, counter

I don't consider myself to be bad at programming, but there's been something troubling me since the past few days.

```
int counter = 3;
++counter;
```

Is the following code above the same as `counter++;`.

Comment: Just as a note, the linked answer refers to JavaScript, while this question concerns Java and also C/C++. However, I am 99% sure they operate in similar fashion.

Comment: @ChrisChambers I will confirm that they do behave the same way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is similar, but not the same.

In your expression it doesn't matter, but if you had something more complicated, like `System.out.println(counter++)`, it would make a big difference.

For example:
`int counter = 3;
System.out.println(counter++)`

This will print 3, then increment counter to 4.

However, if you do

`int counter = 3;
System.out.println(++counter)`

it will print 4 because it increments prior to giving the value as a parameter to the print function.

It's a question of when the increment is performed, the prefix performs it before other operations, postfix performs it after. They have different precedences.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Now, since I am curious, could you explain how it can be different?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Wish I knew this much about programming. I'll accept it in 10 minutes.